# problem with install flutter in sdk licenses

Tags: flutter

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKukw.png)
can anyone help me I have tried many ways to solve this problem. I've tried updating the android SDK, I've downgraded the android SDK the result is still like this

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the SDK in a location that does not contain white spaces in its absolute path like you have in the word "A S U S" and you can update the SDK location accordingly by updating the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME to the new location.